# If Statement Python 2.7.8,Invalid syntax

Tags: python

The Problem is at if statement invalid syntax at A after if statement.Please Help.

```
print("Welcome to the Project Hotel ")
print("Enter the following Pins to Enter the Following Areas  :  ")
print("A = Pin for the Visitor Management is 1111")
print("B = Pin for the Room Management is 2222")
print("C = Pin for the Bill Management is 3333")      

A=int(input("Enter the 4-Digit Pin here -  "))

If A==1111:
    print("Welcome to the Visitor Management Section")    

if A==2222:
    pass

if A==3333:
    print("Total Amount =(Total Room amount + Food amounts + Extras)")
      print("VAT here is 4.5% * (Total Amount)")
      print("Final Amount = Total amount + VAT")
Hotel.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a capital I in your first if statement.

Comment: wow i couldn't have imagined i made such a simple silly mistake thank's for correcting

Answer (score 3):

The "if" statement should be typed in lowercase. Check your indents also, it might be problem on them.

Comment: wow i couldn't have imagined i made such a simple silly mistake thank's for correcting